# How can I make conditional selections using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have the following situation. Given the table

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
             type = c("MC", "MC", "MK", "MC", "MK", "MC"),
             value1 = c(512, 261, 4523, 1004, 1221, 2556),
             value2 = c(726, 4000, 280, 998, 113, 6789))
```

I am trying to find a way to implement the following logic: If for an ID, both types (MC and MK) occur, use value1 from MK and value2 from MC. Otherwise (only the type MC occurs), use MC.

Hence, the final result is supposed to be:

```
data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
             type = c("MC", "MC", "MC", "MC"),
             value1 = c(512, 4523, 1221, 2556),
             value2 = c(726, 4000, 998, 6789))
```

Assuming the type MK is dropped after extracting the value1.

Comment: 2nd df: `Error in data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4), type = c("MC", "MC", "MC",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 4`

Comment: @ Andre Thanks - it's correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency I would definitely prefer @Andre Elrico' answer but here is a `dplyr` option. Try:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                 type = c("MC", "MC", "MK", "MC", "MK", "MC"),
                 value1 = c(512, 261, 4523, 1004, 1221, 2556),
                 value2 = c(726, 4000, 280, 998, 113, 6789)) 
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  reshape(., idvar = "ID", timevar = "type", direction = "wide") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(is.na(value1.MK), value1.MC, value1.MK),
         value2 = ifelse(is.na(value2.MC), value2.MK, value2.MC),
         type = "MC") %>%
  select(ID, type, value1, value2)
# output
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID  type value1 value2
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    MC    512    726
2     2    MC   4523   4000
3     3    MC   1221    998
4     4    MC   2556   6789
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(any(type == "MK"), value1[type=="MK"],value1[type=="MC"]), 
         value2 = value2[type == "MC"]) %>%
  filter(type == "MC")

#     ID type  value1 value2
#  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 MC       512    726
#2     2 MC      4523   4000
#3     3 MC      1221    998
#4     4 MC      2556   6789
```

Here, for `value1` we check value in "MK" if it is present or take corresponding "MC" value instead and for `value2` by default we take "MC" value and keep only rows with `type` "MC". This is assuming every group (`ID`) would have a "MC" `type` row.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution

```
setDT(df1)[,{x=.SD;if(all(c("MC","MK") %in% type)){x$value1[] = last(value1)};first(x)},by=ID]
```

result:

```
#  ID type value1 value2
#1  1   MC    512    726
#2  2   MC   4523   4000
#3  3   MC   1221    998
#4  4   MC   2556   6789
```

---

`dplyr`:

```
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% do(.,(function(x){if(all(c("MC","MK") %in% x$type)){x$value1[] = x$value1[x$type=="MK"]};x[1,]})(.))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID type  value1 value2
#  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 MC       512    726
#2     2 MC      4523   4000
#3     3 MC      1221    998
#4     4 MC      2556   6789
```

Comment: @ Andre. Thanks a lot for a possible solution. I would prefer a solution with dplyr but it's definitely a good start. Cheers